# How to copy maven .m2 repository to Jenkins

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, svn

I have a local .m2 maven repository, I want to upload this repository to Source Code Management like Git or Subversion, and then I want to create a job where it detects that in the Source Code Management it is a Maven Local dependency  so that, the job installs all de dependencyes  to the local Maven that Jenkins is using.

This local repository have lots of maven dependencies that are not in maven repository.

In summary, I have a local Maven repository and I want to use this with a Jenkins that is located in another machine

UPDATE:

Let's see this from another way:

I have the local maven repository form the "computer A" to my local network 
\\ComputerA\Users\Administrador\.m2\repository

What I want is that, using Jenkins from another machine use this repositroy as her local maven repository (Like an Artifactory)

Due to what I am doing I cannot use an Artifactory.

Comment: Do not do this...it does not make sense to checkin artifacts into a version control system...You need to change your build process to deploy the artifacts to a repository manager....also it does not make sense to copy those artifacts to Jenkins ...wrong way...

Answer (score 2):

In a word, don't. Don't upload any binaries to source control. If you absolutely cannot use Nexus or other artifact repository, consider hosting your own web server somewhere and serve them up like that.